# Rails 5: Send reload to set of clients on data update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, websocket

I'm using Rails 5 to make a simple turn based game tracker for an in-person social game (via phones/tablets/etc..)

I want to have all the 'players' in the game (list of sessions/users/...) to reload their browsers automatically once a player has taken an action.

I know that there are live update capabilities such as AJAX and websockets, but they all seem far too weighty for what seems to be a simple problem.  Furthermore, I want to update *other* clients pages, not just the client initiating the action.

Is there a simple solution to send a reload?  Or do I need to code something up in one of the more complicated APIs?

Comment: The way to use AJAX is the easiest way to do in this case. However the `ActionCable` (WebSocket way) in Rails 5 is also quite easy to implement, so if it is possible, you should give it a try.

Comment: Is there a simple example that demonstrates this?  All of the AJAX tutorials I have looked at use AJAX so that a client's actions can update it's own clients page without loading the entire page.

I want to send reloads to *other* clients.  I'll update the question to make this more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the simple trouble, you still can use AJAX to reload user client by making interval request for each XX seconds. The server can return the last action time which can be used for client to determine that it should reload itself or not.

For example, on the controller

```
# SomeController
def get_last_action_time
  # Return the timestamp of the last action
  render json: {last_action_time: "2017-12-29 10:00:42 UTC"}
end
```

on the client

```
function getLocalLastAction () {
  /* return timestamp of the last action on local */
}

function setLocalLastAction (time) {
  /* Store the `time` to somewhere, ex: localStorage */
}

function checkLastAction () {
  $.getJSON("/get_last_action_time", function (data) {
    if (getLocalLastAction() < data.last_action_time) {
      /* destroy the interval */
      setLocalLastAction(data.last_action_time)
      /* do the reload page */
    } else {
      /* do nothing */
    }
  })
}

// Check every 1 second, shouldn't be too short due to performance
var checking = setInterval(checkLastAction, 1000)
```

Then when user A do an action, the server `last_action_time` will change, hence client of other users will be reloaded at most after 1 second.

This way is old but quite easy to do in some simple case, and when you implement together with actions caching, the performance of app still acceptable. In the more complicated cases, I suggest using WebSocket solution for

- Full control
- Low latency
- Better performance for app

Comment: It seems the only advantage here over a regular reload is that the app doesn't have to reload the whole page?  I suppose it also means the user page doesn't keep reloading underneath them...

Comment: @DavidLjungMadison No it doesn't mean reload the whole page or not. The problem it solves that when a user A stay at LA and do an action, user B at CA will automatically reload the page after less than 1 second. The AJAX only help you to check if someone just did something or not then reload the page if necessary.

Comment: Right - I mean that it saves you from reloading the page, but the client still needs to poll/load data from the server every so often.  In this case it's the actiontime instead of the whole page, which is an improvement.  It'd be nice to figure out an easy way to hold connections to each client and call the reload from the server directly.

Comment: @DavidLjungMadison yes, you are correct, the only way to avoid polling is Server push or Websocket which both base on more complex implementation. However, as said, the `ActionCable` of Rails 5 is very handful, so I think you should give it a try.

Comment: Implemented something like this and it basically works.  As a note, your code needs a change so that it doesn't reload on the first check, probably by testing for the last active reload not being 0.

Comment: ActionCable looks interesting - I'll see if I can find a simple step-by-step guide to setting up a single send of data, I don't have the time to learn everything it has to offer right now.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @yeuem1vannam's answer, here is the final code I used that helps avoid the race condition of a page loading old information while the time is being updated and then the javascript updating the time and getting the new time, and hence missing the reload.

The javascript code:

```
var actionChecker;

function doneChecking () {
  clearInterval(actionChecker);
}

function checkLastAction () {
  // Get the game ID from the html access span
  var dataId = document.getElementById('javascript_data_access');
  if (!dataId) return doneChecking();
  var initActionTime = dataId.getAttribute('init_last_action_time');
  if (!initActionTime) return doneChecking();

  dataId = dataId.getAttribute('game_number');
  if (!dataId) return doneChecking();

  // Get the last action time
  var ret = $.getJSON("/get_last_action_time/"+dataId, function (data) {
    var lastActionTime = data.last_action_time;
    if (!lastActionTime) return doneChecking();
    if (lastActionTime>initActionTime) {
      location.reload();
    }
  })
}

window.onload = function() {
  // Check every 1 second, shouldn't be too short due to performance
  actionChecker = setInterval(checkLastAction, 1000);
}
```

The controller's action:

```
  def get_last_action_time
    last_time = nil
    begin
      @game = Game.find_by_id(params[:id])
      # Return the timestamp of the last action
      last_time = (@game && !@game.endTime) ? @game.reloadTime.to_i : 0
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
      last_time = 0
    end
    # Stop bugging us after 30m, we should have moved on from this page
    last_time==0 if (last_time!=0 && (milliseconds - last_time)>30*60*1000)
    render json: {last_action_time: last_time}
  end
```

And then in the html.erb:

```
<span id='javascript_data_access' game_number=<%= params[:id] %> init_last_action_time=<%= @game.reloadTime %>></span>
```

Obviously you need to add reloadTime to your model and also endTime if there's a time you no longer want to check for reloads anymore.

Seems to be working fine so far, you have to make sure that you're careful about who is in charge of setting reloadTime.  If two pages set reloadTime everytime they reload, you'll be stuck in a reload loop battle between the two pages.